# Getting all indices of a value

Tags: list, haskell, indexing

Im trying to create a haskell function where all the indices of an occurence of a value in a list are returned as a list, so like

```
indices 3 [1,2,3,3,7]
```

gives [2, 3] as output. I am very new to Haskell and couldnt find something useful. I tried using filter, but all i got working is getting a list of [3, 3] but not the actual indices. It would be cool if you could give me a little hint.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a pretty common pattern in functional programming, sometimes called decorate-process-undecorate. The idea is that you want to attach some extra information to each of the elements in your list, filter using a slightly altered version of the filter you would have done normally, then strip that extra information away.

```
indicies n = undecorate . filter predicate . decorate where
  decorate   = ...
  predicate  = ...
  undecodate = ...
```

When trying to code `decorate` I suggest taking a look at the function `zip`:

```
zip :: [a] -> [b] -> [(a, b)]
```

Consider its effect on infinite lists, too, such as `repeat 1` or `[1,3,...]`. When trying to code `undecorate` you'll likely want to `map`:

```
map :: (a -> b) -> [a] -> [b]
```

Finally, don't worry about the efficiency of this process. In a strict language, decorate-filter-undecorate might require 3 traversals of the list. In a non-strict language like Haskell the compiler will automatically merge the 3 inner loops into a single one.

Comment: Thank you, that sounds very clear, i will try getting the individual parts together, the general idea became clear to me!

Comment: I used your approach and got the following code which does exactly what i want! `print (map (fst) (filter (\(x, y) -> y == 3) (zip [1..] [1,3,3,7])))`