# Filter bigger element of two lists

Tags: list, haskell, filter

I am trying to write a Haskell programm which outputs a list of primes, but only those where the square is bigger than the product of the previous and following prime. For example, given

```
primes = [2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17]
-- keep  5 since  5² > 3*7
-- keep 11 since 11² > 7*13
```

My plan was to create the list of the squares and the neighbour products and then use a filter to output only those elements of the list of primes where the square is bigger than the neighbour products.
This is what I have so far

```
products :: [Int]
products = zipWith (*) primes (drop 2 primes)

squares :: [Int]
squares = zipWith (*) (drop 1 primes) (drop 1 primes)

goodPrimes :: [Int]
goodPrimes = filter (\products, squares -> squares > products) (drop 1 primes)
```

Everything works but the `goodPrimes`  function.
I hope everything is clear and that someone can help me.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. — Please try to ask _concrete_ questions, like “why do I get this particular error message”, not just “it's not working, please somebody help me”. What I can say right away is that `(\products, squares -> ...)` is not valid syntax. You can either write a two-argument lambda as `(\products squares -> ...)`, or a lambda with a single tuple argument `(\(products, squares) -> ...)`. Do you understand the difference?

Answer (score 5):

You had a syntax error in your `goodPrimes` lambda (a comma between params).

We also need to pair the elements of your products, squares, and primes lists (using `zip3`).

```hs
primes :: [Int]
primes = [2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17]

squares :: [Int]
squares = zipWith (*) (tail primes) (tail primes)

products :: [Int]
products = zipWith (*) primes (drop 2 primes)

goodPrimes :: [Int]
goodPrimes = fmap (\(prime, _, _) -> prime)
  $ filter (\(prime, prod, square) -> square > prod)
  $ zip3 (tail primes) products squares
```

We can inline the computation of the square to make `goodPrimes` cleaner, we can then delete `squares`.

```hs
goodPrimes :: [Int]
goodPrimes = fmap fst
  $ filter (\(prime, prod) -> prime * prime > prod)
  $ zip (tail primes) products
```

```
λ> goodPrimes
[5,11]
```

Comment: Ah okay, looks good, thank you. I am still very new to Haskell so I didn´t know how to use the filter function correctly

Comment: @MichaWiedenmann there was no missing `)` in OP's question.

Comment: But noted, I've added an intermediate step with with the `zip3` version

Answer (score 3):

You were in the right direction, but not quite. To continue your line of thought we could write

```
goodPrimes = -- filter (\products, squares -> squares > products) (drop 1 primes)
  map (\ (_,_,p) -> p) $
    filter (\ (product, square, prime) -> square > product ) 
           (zip3 products 
                 squares
                 (drop 1 primes))
```

packaging the squares, the products, and the primes together into triples, filtering the triples, and then recovering the primes back. This is known as [decorate-process-undecorate](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23596178/849891) paradigm, or ["Schwartzian transform"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwartzian_transform) in the olden days of yore.

Or we could re-implement `filter` with a list comprehension, fusing all the definitions and simplifying the result to

```
goodPrimes2 = 
  [ prime | ((prod, sq), prime) <- products `zip` squares `zip` drop 1 primes
          , sq > prod ]
 =
  [ prime | ((prod, sq), prime) <- 
               zipWith (*) primes (drop 2 primes)
                 `zip` zipWith (*) (drop 1 primes) (drop 1 primes)
                   `zip` drop 1 primes
          , sq > prod ]
 =
  [ p1    | ((p0, p2), p1) <- 
               primes `zip` (drop 2 primes) `zip` drop 1 primes
          , p1*p1 > p0*p2]
 =
  [ p1    | (p0:p1:p2:_) <- iterate tail primes  -- or (tails primes)
          , p1*p1 > p0*p2]
```

`(p0:p1:p2:_)` is a list which, in pseudocode, could be written as `[p0, p1, p2, ...]`, and `iterate tail` (or `tails`) produces a list of progressive tails of its input list, here `primes`.

There's no reuse of `product`s and `square`s, so no point in pre-calculating those lists.

Trying it out:

```
> take 20 primes
[2,3,5,7,11,13,17,19,23,29,31,37,41,43,47,53,59,61,67,71]

> take 10 goodPrimes2
[5,11,17,29,37,41,53,59,67,71]
```

---

It can be nice to play with code, to shake it until it settles into something simple and clear. The sequence could be continued as

```
 =
  [ p1    | (p0:p1:p2:_) <- iterate tail primes  -- or (tails primes)
          , p1*p1 > p0*p2]
 =
  concatMap (\ case (p0:p1:p2:_) -> [p1 | p1*p1 > p0*p2] )
            (tails primes)
 =
  tails primes >>= (\ case (p0:p1:p2:_) -> [p1 | p1*p1 > p0*p2] )
```

Thus,

```
goodPrimes3 = foo primes
   where
   foo = tails >=> (\ case (p0:p1:p2:_) -> [p1 | p1*p1 > p0*p2] )
```

but these last variants which treat lists as a "monad" are probably not interesting for you right now.

Incidentally, the mapping on progressive tails is a primitive in Common Lisp, known as [`maplist`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_mapc_.htm), and the concat-mapping ("flatmapping" as it is known in other languages) on tails is also a primitive there, [`mapcon`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_mapc_.htm) (so in Haskell, `mapcon f = (tails >=> f)`).

Comment: Thank you, this is a great solution and I even understand the way it works!

Comment: nice to hear it, you're welcome . :) main lesson is, don't be afraid to play with it, to shake the code until it settles into something simple and nice.

Answer (score 2):

You can take this a step further by using `zip3` to get tuples containing all three relevant values; then a simple list comprehension will give you the final result.

```
> zip3 <*> tail <*> tail.tail $ primes
[(2,3,5),(3,5,7),(5,7,11),(7,11,13),(11,13,17)]
> [ y | (x, y, z) <- zip3 <*> tail <*> tail.tail $ primes, y*y > x*z]
[5,11]
```

`zip <*> tail $ primes` is a nice idiom for generating a list of adjacent pairs. I'm not sure `zip3 <*> tail <*> tail.tail $ primes` is quite as nice. The explicit form is `zip3 primes (tail primes) (tail (tail primes))`.